# Updating the Website virtual directory (MSI -Installshield)

Tags: installshield

I am using InstallShield 2010 I am trying to create an installation MSI which will modify a Web application's virtual directory path under the "Default Web Site".  I was trying many way in the Installation Designer but I can't mange to overwrite the changes.  It is possible to do it or do I need to implement custom actions.

Thanks
Thurein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to update the root directory of the default website itself?  ( I.E. change it from C:\InetPub to something else )   If so, InstallShield doesn't support this.   You can create additional virtual directories and you can create additional websites responding on different ip's, ports or host headers but you can't update the root default website out of concern of messing up existing applications and content.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to update the virtual directory of a web application under the Default Web Site (e.g. from "C:\InetPub\wwwroot\dirA" to "C:\InetPub\wwwroot\dirB".  Is it not possible?

Comment: I'm 99% certain that it is not possible unless you use a custom action to interact with the IIS metabase directly to do it.  The reason is the data model requires you to define a website and then a virtual directory and the usual case is deploying a virtual directory to the default website but you don't want to molest the root.

Michael Urman is an InstallShield employee who is a user here.  He can take my 99% answer to 100%.   You can also ask over at http://community.installshield.com